# SpringBoot: Configuration Production Vs Development environments

Tags: java, spring-boot

I have a problem with SpringBoot 1.5.1. I've create `application.properties` and `application-dev.properties` for my dev enviroment.

The main difference is the persistence: in production (`application.properties`) there is a JNDI (configured on Tomcat) and in dev there is a local db (H2).

This is my conf in `application.properties`:

```
spring.datasource.jndi-name=jdbc/db
```

And this is the `application-dev.properties`:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:file:~/db
spring.datasource.username=sa
spring.datasource.password=
spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.h2.Driver
```

But when I'm starting in with dev profile

```
2017-02-24 15:25:39.948  INFO 7912 --- [           main] it.geny.MmqApplication                   : The following profiles are active: dev
```

my app stops because it didn't find the JNDI jdbc/db!!!! I'm trying to change log configuration on my `application-dev.properties` and it works! But not the changes on persistence configuration.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 11, accepted):

All the properties of `application-dev.properties` overrides the properties in `application.properties`. But if in `application.properties` are properties which are not set in the dev one they will be also inlcuded to the context. And if the property `spring.datasource.jndi-name` is enabled all the `spring.datasource` properties are ignored.

The solution is to create another properties file like `application-prod.properties` and set the `spring.datasource.jndi-name` there. The datasource stuff can stay in `application-dev.properties`.

In your `application.properties` file you should enable the profile you like to use: `spring.profiles.active=prod` or `spring.profiles.active=dev`

Comment: We do something similar - often with several deployment tiers (dev, dev2, qa, qa2, uat, prod, etc.). Rather than using different property file names, we provide different folders for tier-specific property files under /src/main/resources.  At startup, we provide an environment variable that identifies the deployment tier (say qa2) and this is used to locate any tier-specific config data.